# How to use LIKE keyword when calling external program passing an array

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have the following RPGLE program:

```
dmypgm            pr                  extpgm('MYPGM')
d  myarr                              like(myarr)
d  somevar                            like(somevar)

d myarr           s             64a   dim(100)
d somevar         s             65a

/free
 callp mypgm(myarr: somevar);
 *inlr = *on;
/end-free
```

When I attempt to compile this on a V6R1 box I get the error message:

```
RNF5343 30      1 Array has too many omitted indexes; specification is ignored.
```

Some [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.iseries.ilerpg.doc%2Fevfrnf401371.htm) tells me:

> RNF5343
>
> Array has too many omitted indexes; specification is ignored.
>
> 30
>
> Cause . . . . . : The number of omitted indexes for the array used as
>   an operand on the right side of an assignment operator is greater than
>   the number of omitted indexes for the array specified as the result of
>   the assignment.
>
> Recovery . . . : Reduce the number of omitted indexes for the operand;
>   or increase the number of omitted indexes for the result. Compile
>   again.

Which is less than helpful since this is a program call rather than trying to assign a value (like with an `EVAL` statement or something).

If I change the declaration of my external program call to:

```
dmypgm            pr                  extpgm('MYPGM')
d  myarr                        64a   dim(100)
d  somevar                            like(somevar)
```

the program will compile just fine.

So how do I use the `LIKE` keyword with an array for an external program definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the data type, length, data type and CCSID are inherited with LIKE.
To pass an array, use both LIKE and DIM:

```
dmypgm            pr                  extpgm('MYPGM')
d  myarr                              like(myarr) dim(%elem(myarr))
d  somevar                            like(somevar)

d myarr           s             64a   dim(100)
d somevar         s             65a
```

See the [6.1 Infocenter LIKE() keyword](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc092508551.htm).